# Nodejs Express redirecting does not work

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, post, http-redirect

I'm currently trying to redirect a user to a success screen after he click the login button. Everything seems to be working fine but the page does not change. Tried searching online but none of the solution helped.

**Update It seems that the root cause is because of '/' in routes. Changed it to '/home' and it works now**

**Solved**

Below is my html, server and route codes

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>

   <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
   </script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../public/css/style.css">

  </head>
<body>
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="loginController">
  <div class="container">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <h1 class="welcome text-center" style="text-align:center;">Welcome</h1>

    <div class="card card-container">
    <!--
    <h2 class='login_title text-center'>Login</h2>
    -->
    <hr>

        <form class="form-signin">

            <p class="input_title">Username:</p>
            <input type="text" id="inputEmail" class="login_box" ng-model="username" required autofocus>
            <p class="input_title">Password</p>
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="login_box" ng-model="password" required>
         <br>
         <br>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" ng-click="sub()">Login</button>
        </form><!-- /form -->
    </div><!-- /card-container -->
  </div><!-- /container -->

 </div>

  <script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller("loginController", function($scope,$http) {

  $scope.sub = function() {

    var data = {
        username: $scope.username,
        password: $scope.password

    }

     var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-
  urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
            }
        }


    $http.post('/login', data, config)
.then(
   function(response){
     console.log('action on success');
   }, 
   function(response){
           console.log('action on error');
   }
);

}

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var config = require('./config');


var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morgan('dev'));


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));
require('./app/routes')(app);


app.listen(3000,function(err){

if(err){

console.log(err);
}
else{

console.log("Listening on port 3000");
}

});
```

**route.js**

```
module.exports = function (app) {


app.get('/',function(req,res){

res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');


});

app.post('/login', function(req, res){
console.log("post here!");
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html")
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/success.html');
//res.redirect(__dirname + '/app/views/success.html');
res.end;

});
```

[cmd response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ha5zg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my suggestions,

- If you are trying to redirect in routes files then use:

  ```
  return res.redirect('your url');
  ```
- If you are trying to redirect in ajax files then use:

  ```
  window.location.href = 'your url';
  ```

Comment: Hi, I have just tried what you suggested e.g return res.redirect('./views/success.html'); in my routes.js but it still does not work

Comment: i think you are using ajax when you click on login button ajax call to post /login button use 2nd option..

Comment: I have manage to find the problem, it seems that because of app.get('/',function(req,res){

res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');


}); it will always go back to index.html even if it is success. I changed '/' to   '/home' and it seems to be working fine now